# How to ignore a part of a pattern to use preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'd like to ignore what's inside a href element and make the function search with the rest of the pattern, I'd like it to be something like this:

```
preg_match('|<tr><td class="even"><a href="#">(.*?)</a></td>|', $content, $value)
```

Originally the href has `/?tab=episode&seriesid=121361&seasonid=364731&id=3436411&amp;lid=16` but it's something I'd like the function to ignore.

**EDITED:**
I'd like to match the `2` from `<td class="even"><a href="/?tab=episode&seriesid=121361&seasonid=364731&id=3436411&amp;lid=16">2</a></td>` but not just 1, i'll match more later and they have differents href values so i want a regex that means this href maybe variable. I don't know if i explained well, my english is not very good.

Comment: Could you please add an example of what you want to match and what not and what the current problem with your regex is?

Comment: @SourceOverflow edited right now

Comment: `<a href="[^"]*">` might be worth a shot. You should use a dom parser though.

Comment: @Scuzzy Yes it worked, thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `<a href="[^"]*">` it will match anything that isn't a `"` character.

Ideally you want to use a dom parser, [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php). SimpleXML with XPath is a good tool.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are searching for the following regex:

```
<tr><td class="even"><a href=".*">(.*)</a></td>
```

This will match all of these:

```
<tr><td class="even"><a href="/?tab=episode&seriesid=121361&seasonid=36ad31&id=3436411&amp;lid=16">2</a></td>
<tr><td class="even"><a href="/?tab=episode&seriesid=121361&seasonid=36aw31&id=3436411&amp;lid=16">1</a></td>
<tr><td class="even"><a href="/?tab=episode&adwadsonid=364731&id=3436411&amp;lid=16">Hallo</a></td>
<tr><td class="even"><a href="/?tab=episode&serwdadw1&seasonid=364731&id=3436411&amp;lid=16">Test</a></td>
```

I Also kept your `(.*)` as I am assuming you are using that group later.

If you want to search for a specific value in the a-tag content just replace `(.*)`with that.